# How do you set cloudfront to use https without a domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-acm

I want to set up https for my s3 bucket so I figured I do it via cloudfront

I have a CF distribution and requested a domain name via route 53, which can take 3 days apparently

I've seen lots of tutorials but they all require a domain name to be entered when requesting a certificate. is it possible to do with just CF and s3

so instead of going to do `http://my-bucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/` I can access `https://my-bucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/`

how can I do this?

I tried putting in my cloudfront domain into the ACM request but it rejected it

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/

Comment: Let me know if the link above doesn't work for you.

Comment: Is the answer to this that it's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

The SSL will not be valid for that domain name. You will however, be able to access the CloudFront distribution via HTTPS.

Try accessing the CLoudFront hostname in the browser using HTTPS.

Comment: I get access denied doing that?

Comment: Do you have an alias name on it?

Comment: If you want a custom domain then yes this must be setup